# HTTP working HTTPS not working

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost

I set up Comodo SSL on CentOS 6.7 and Apache/2.2.15 and we are running a CakePHP application on the server. When I go to http/domain its working but when I go to httpS/domain it says 404 Not Found (even though I see lock icon and https in green color).

Here's part of my etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file:

```
Include conf.d/*.conf 
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin info@domain
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/webroot/
ServerName domain
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs>
    Allowoverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf contains:

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/webroot/
ServerName domain
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/domain.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/domain.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

I've done httpd stop and start multiple times, and also tried httpS/domain:80 but that gives an error: This webpage is not available (ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED).

Can the DocumentRoot be the same? If not then how do I manage that since copy/pasting our application code in another folder is not feasible.

Any thoughts on what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you installed and enabled `mod_ssl`? Do you see any error in apache error_log ?

Comment: yes mod_ssl is installed.
Package 1:mod_ssl-2.2.15-47.el6.centos.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Comment: Anything in apache error_log?

Comment: was checking that only in /var/log/httpd - didn't see anything related to HTTPS. Is there any specific log file I should look at? Thanks

Comment: usually it is under: `/var/log/httpd/error_log`, any error can be noted. And what do you mean by: "..also tried httpS/domain:80". You should check the site as `https://domain`

Comment: In your http block you have `Allowoverride All` for the /var/www/vohsts/domain/httpdocs directory, which is missing from the SSL block - is there a .htaccess file in that dir which is responsible for enabling access to the webapp? Your SSL config is working as you are getting a valid SSL connection when you try to access the https page, so this might be a permissions issue.

Comment: Carcer - there's no .htaccess file in /httpd /httpd/conf or /httpd/conf.d folders. I then added the following at the end of ssl.conf and restarted but that didn't help either.
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs>
    Allowoverride All
</Directory>

Comment: @deejee, try to add your ssl-site configuration in a seperate virtual host file rather than in ssl.conf file and restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `<VirtualHost *:443>` to `<VirtualHost domain.com:443>` and it worked.

Answer (score -4):

Take a look at this: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#example

```
 server {
        listen              443 ssl;
        keepalive_timeout   70;

        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers         AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:RC4-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:RC4-MD5;
        ssl_certificate     /usr/local/nginx/conf/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/conf/cert.key;
        ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    }
```

especially:

```
  listen              443 ssl;
   ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_ciphers         AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:RC4-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:RC4-MD5;
```

Comment: As far as I can tell from the original question, it has nothing to do with `nginx`.

Comment: Oh sorry. I overread from another question. But the principle is the same, just google the alternativ commands for Apache2

Comment: My feeling is that you should either do that yourself, and make this answer fit for the question, or delete it so it doesn't keep collecting downvotes.  It's up to you, though.